# generate multiple values during iteration

Tags: racket

Is there a way I can generate multiple values in `for/list` during each iteration and have the results "flattened"?

For instance:

```
(for/list ([i (range n)]) (values i (+ i 1)))
```

I'd like the result to be `(list 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 ...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is very much relevant to https://github.com/racket/racket/pull/2483. In the link, you will find:

- An unmerged PR that lets you write `(for/append-list ([i (range n)]) (list i (+ i 1)))`.
- My proposal to let you write `(for/list* ([i (range n)]) (values i (+ i 1)))` (with caveat, see the link for more details).

But since these don't exist in Racket yet, the easiest way to get what you want is:

```
(append* (for/list ([i (range n)]) (list i (+ i 1))))
```

Comment: `(apply append (list (list 1 2) (list 2 3)))` is same as `(append* (list (list 1 2) (list 2 3)))`, but `append` alone is not the same as `append*`.

Comment: Relevant documentations: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._append%29%29 and https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._append%2A%29%29